# XML Serialization List of Objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Looking at the Microsoft article on XML Serialization:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx

They give an example under "Serializing an Array of Objects" as below:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Item [] ItemsOrders
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemID
    public decimal ItemPrice
}
```

With output:

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>aaa111</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>34.22</ItemPrice>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemID>bbb222</ItemID>
            <ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

What bothers me is the "Items" tag.  Seems to me like only the "Item" tag should be a child of "PurchaseOrder".  The "Items" tag seems unnecessary and confusing.  I could be wrong.

Is there a way to get this example to serialize like this:

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>aaa111</ItemID>
        <ItemPrice>34.22</ItemPrice>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>bbb222</ItemID>
        <ItemPrice>2.89</ItemPrice>
    </Item>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: Imagine you had two collections: Orders and Invoices. You'll want an `<Orders>` element and an `<Invoices>` element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can control the serialization using attributes.From "[Controlling XML Serialization using Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx)": To remove the element which stands for the entire array, use the `[XmlElement]` attribute:

> ```
> public class Group{
>     [XmlElement]
>     public Employee[] Employees;
> }
> ```

this produces

> ```
> <Group>
>     <Employees>
>         <Name>Haley</Name>
>     </Employees>
>     <Employees>
>         <Name>Noriko</Name>
>     </Employees>
>     <Employees>
>         <Name>Marco</Name>
>     </Employees>
> </Group>
> ```

Comment: Using `XmlElement` will suppress the "collection" element. f you want the collection element, use `XmlArray` attribute so the collection is serialized and `XmlArrayItem` to control the name and type when the individual items are serialized. The same goes for deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `XmlElement` attribute to specify the name you want to use for each item:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var order = new PurchaseOrder { ItemsOrders = new Item[2] };

            order.ItemsOrders[0] = new Item { ItemID = "1", ItemPrice = 1723 };
            order.ItemsOrders[1] = new Item { ItemID = "2", ItemPrice = 4711 };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PurchaseOrder));

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, order);

                Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public Item[] ItemsOrders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string ItemID { get; set; }

        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Item>
    <ItemID>1</ItemID>
    <ItemPrice>1723</ItemPrice>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>2</ItemID>
    <ItemPrice>4711</ItemPrice>
  </Item>
</PurchaseOrder>
Press any key to continue . . .
```